# How do I remove subset of array of documents in javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've the following objects and I wanted to remove the elements that are not part of the arrayTwo. How can I do that in a lodash way. I want to remove everything from ArrayOne except those in ArrayTwo

```
ArrayOne = [
  {
    A1: {},
    B1: 'string'
  }, {
    A2: {},
    B2: 'string'
  }, {
    A3: {},
    B3: 'string'
  }, {
    A4: {},
    B4: 'string'
  }
];

ArrayTwo = [
  { A1: {} },
  { A2: {} }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
ArrayOne = [
  {
    A1: {},
    B1: 'string'
  }, {
    A2: {},
    B2: 'string'                
  }
];
```

Comment: You want to delete objects containing any key from the `ArrayTwo` array or just the properties inside these objects?

Comment: I want to keep those objects in ArrayOne that has got an array inside the document which is part of ArrayTwo and delete the rest.

Comment: Please add expected result.

Comment: Edited my question for expected result

Comment: `Array2` isn't a valid object.

Comment: It's still invalid. It should be `[{A1:[]}, {A2:[]}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionWith) with [`_.isMatch()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isMatch) as the comparator function:

```js
var ArrayOne = [{"A1":{},"B1":"string"},{"A2":{},"B2":"string"},{"A3":{},"B3":"string"},{"A4":{},"B4":"string"}];

var ArrayTwo = [
  { A1: {} },
  { A2: {} }
];

var result = _.intersectionWith(ArrayOne, ArrayTwo, _.isMatch);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is so cool. I didn't know that I can use intersection even if both objects schema is different.

Comment: `_.intersectionWith()` just let you use whatever comperator function you want. The `_.isMatch()` function enables you to compare different schemas and declare a match if some properties exist on both objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop to check if anything in ArrayTwo exists in ArrayOne

```js
ArrayOne = [{
  A1: {},
  B1: 'string'
}, {
  A2: {},
  B2: 'string'
}, {
  A3: {},
  B3: 'string'
}, {
  A4: {},
  B4: 'string'
}];

ArrayTwo = [{
    A1: {}
  },
  {
    A2: {}
  }
];

ArrayThree = [];
for (var i in ArrayOne) {
  loop: for (var j in ArrayTwo) {
    for (var k in ArrayTwo[j]) {
      if (JSON.stringify(ArrayOne[i][k]) == JSON.stringify(ArrayTwo[j][k])) {
        ArrayThree.push(ArrayOne[i]);
        break loop;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(ArrayThree);
```